# Interpolation of stock price

Tags: python-3.x

I have been struggling with this code on quadratic interpolation of 30days stock adjusted closing price of AAPL. I had the error message after running the code.
what could be the problem? I have tried manipulating the data to no success.

> ValueError: x and y arrays must be equal in length along interpolation axis.

```
from pandas_datareader import data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import googlefinance
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as interp1d
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d


ticker = ['AAPL','SPY']
data_source = 'google'
start_date = '2017-11-15'
end_date = '2017-12-15'

panel_data=data.DataReader(ticker,data_source,start_date,end_date)
adj_close = panel_data.loc['Close']


end = np.shape(adj_close)[0]
adj_x = np.linspace(0, end, end, endpoint=True)

# Interpolating points in the entire function.
interp_Linear = interp1d(adj_x, adj_close, kind='linear')
interp_adjclose = interp_Linear(adj_x)

# Plotting the interpolation.
plt.figure()
plt.plot(adj_x, adj_close, 'ro', adj_x, interp_adjclose, 'k--')
plt.xlabel('Days')
plt.ylabel('Adjusted Close Price')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Apparently the arrays `adj_x` and `adj_close` are not equal in size.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar assignment, wherein instead of your 'adj_close', I converted the same into `numpy.array(adj_close).ravel()`. And it worked for me then. I got the same error before.